# How do I dynamically remove and add back component in angular2?

Tags: angular

I have a component defined "FancyButton". I have it here in the template:

```
...
<div class="container">
  <div class="fancy">
    <fancybutton></fancybutton>
  </div>
  <button (click)="removeFancyButton">Remove</button>
  <button (click)="addFancyButton">Add</button>
</div>
...
```

My question is, How can I programatically remove:

```
  <div class="fancy">
    <fancybutton></fancybutton>
  </div>
```

When I click on the remove button? Conversely, how do I add it back in? I would like it to trigger ngOnDestroy if possible, and if its "re-added", trigger ngOnInit when added back in.

This is my fancy-button component, below is the parent template that i have the fancy-button integrated in within the home.component.html:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'fancy-button',
  template: `<button>clickme</button>`
})
export class FancyButton {}

@Component({
  selector: 'home',  // <home></home>
  providers: [
    Title
  ],
  styleUrls: [ './home.component.css' ],
  templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give [***ngIf**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgIf-directive.html) a try, it removes the dom element when it isn't supposed to be shown and conversely adds the dom element when it is

> Removes or recreates a portion of the DOM tree based on an {expression}.

```
...
<div class="container">
  <div *ngIf="showButton" class="fancy">
    <fancybutton></fancybutton>
  </div>
  <button (click)="removeFancyButton">Remove</button>
  <button (click)="addFancyButton">Add</button>
</div>
...

@Component({
  selector: 'home',  // <home></home>
  providers: [
    Title
  ],
  styleUrls: [ './home.component.css' ],
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  directives: [FancyButton],
})
export class Home {
    showButton: Boolean = true;

    addFancyButton() {
        // Do everything you need to
        this.showButton = true;
    }
    removeFancyButton() {
        // Do everything you need to
        this.showButton = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

declare some component property like isFancyBtnVisible = true and change it on click. Then use *ngIf="isFancyBtnVisible" on your button component

Answer (score 0):

If you use *ngIf it will call ngOnOnit when true and ngOnDestroy when false.

`<fancy-button *ngIf="showButton"></fancy-button>`

Answer (score 0):

You can only remove components imperatively that were added imperatively. For an example see [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468). Otherwise use `*ngIf="expr"`. If the expression is false, the content is removed.